# In parametric equations, is "$r$" conventionally defined as the length of curve? If not what exactly is $r$?

Tags: calculus, parametric

What is $r$ exactly? I know it can be tabled to get $x$ and $y$ points. Is $r$ a function to get the length of the curve for any angle put into it?
[image]

Comment: No, in your example, $r$ has nothing to do with arc length. Rather,, $r$ is the (radial) distance to the point, measured from the origin. Typically, $r$ will be a function of $\theta$, which is the angle that the radius makes to the $x$-axis. Here, the function is of the simplest nature: $f(\theta)=\theta-1$. When the function’s value is negative, you have to walk in the opposite direction to the direction pointed at by $\theta$.

Comment: $r$ and $\theta$ are traditionally used as the variables in [polar coordinates.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).  $r$ measures the distance from the origin and $\theta$ measures the angle counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis.

Comment: To be clear, arc length is distance along a curve, by following the curve.
In your exercise, and most polar coordinate, r is typically direct distance from the pole, otherwise known as the origin to the point.  Does that make the distinction from radius clear?

Comment: Yes! Thanks Lubin, Ross Milikan and nickalh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. No, in your example, r has nothing to do with arc length. Rather, r is the (radial) distance to the point, measured from the origin. Typically, r will be a function of θ, which is the angle that the radius makes to the x-axis. Here, the function is of the simplest nature: f(θ)=θ−1. Also, when the function’s value is negative, you have to walk in the opposite direction to the direction pointed at by θ.

B. r  and θ are traditionally used as the variables in polar coordinates. r measures the distance from the origin and θ measures the angle counterclockwise from the positive x axis.

C. To be clear, arc length is distance along a curve, by following the curve. In your exercise, and most polar coordinate, r is typically direct distance from the pole, otherwise known as the origin to the point. Does that make the distinction from radius clear?

Credit to @Lubin and Ross Millikan for first "answers".

Comment: Thanks, how is that "r" function related to $\alpha and \beta$? for instance if i wanted to find the area between 1 and $\pi$. Intuitively I'd want to input 0 and $\pi$ into the function to cover the 1st and 2nd quadrant but that intuition is wrong.

Comment: If you're looking to find area in polar coordinates, start by searching google, this site, etc.  Then ask another question, using what you find as a basis.  Also, just like in xy coordinates, negative r or y values affect the integral.  However, unlike xy graphs be aware r being negative is not always obvious from the graph.  In your example, r is probably squared though. @nvs0000